# Java FXML ProgressBar won't update until all work is completed

Tags: multithreading, javafx, progress-bar, desktop-application, scenebuilder

I'm trying to learn about Java FX using Scene Builder and NetBeans by porting a command-line Java app and have got it mostly working. However neither the progress-bar nor text-area updates until the worker is finished The "Process Images" button doesn't indicate that is has been clicked either, 5 or more seconds later the cursor shows that the app is busy.  I started the project using NetBeans->New Project->JavaFX->Java FXML Application.  My code is in the Controller file.

I've learned (thanks, Google) that this is normal behavior for this kind of GUI and that the updates need to be in their own threads but not how to create the threads that I need.

I created a nested thread just to increment the progress bar, it didn't work.  I then created a nested thread for the worker which used the progress thread, nothing changed.  I then nested the progress thread in the nested worker and still no change.  The worker method/thread manages a list of files filtering them and submitting the correct ones one at a time to a method that corrects any errors that may be found. The worker thread is responsible for updating the progress bar, the updates to the text area are the responsibility of the method that 'fixes' the files.

This button click starts the processing.

```
    @FXML
private void handleBtnProcessImagesClick(ActionEvent event) {
    btnProcess.setText("Processing");
    if (!sourceDirExists) {
        updateLog("Need valid source folder to process images.",
                WARNING);
        return;
    }
    sourceDir = new File(txtFldSourceFolder.getText());
    createDestFolder();
    //processFiles();
    ThreadProcessImages pf = new ThreadProcessImages();
    pf.run();
}
```

Main Worker

```
class ThreadProcessImages extends Thread {

    /**
 * manage the progress bar while calculations are running
 */
class ThreadProgress extends Thread {

    double progress = 0.0;
    double max = 1.0 - 0.0005;

    ThreadProgress(double progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (progress == 0.0) {
            progressBar.setStyle("-fx-accent: SKYBLUE;");
            progressBar.setProgress(0.0);
            System.out.println("Thread start.");
        } else if (progress >= max) {
            progressBar.setStyle("-fx-accent: SPRINGGREEN;");
            progressBar.setProgress(1.0);
            System.out.println("Thread end.");
        } else {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);

        }
    }

}
@Override
    public void run() {
        if (chkBoxSaveEdits.isSelected() && isEdited) {
            try {
                appProps.saveProperties();
                isEdited = false;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                updateLog("processFiles can't save edits.", SEVERE);
            }

        }
        if (chkBxVerbose.isSelected()) {
            updateLog("FileName" + Common.COMMA + "HighCut" + Common.COMMA
                    + "LowCut" + Common.COMMA + "MaxDN" + Common.COMMA + "MinDN"
                    + Common.COMMA + "NewMax" + Common.COMMA + "newMin"
                    + Common.COMMA + "numHighs" + Common.COMMA + "numLows");
        }

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        // get a sorted list of files in the folder
        File[] listOfFiles = sourceDir.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, (f1, f2) -> f1.compareTo(f2));

        // ignores directoriesI
        int numFilesFound = 0;
        int numTIFsFound = 0;
        double progBarMax = (double) listOfFiles.length;
        ThreadProgress progThread = new ThreadProgress(0.0);
        progThread.run();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1l, 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FixBsPixController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        for (File inFile : listOfFiles) { // Filter files
            if (inFile.isFile()) {  // exclude folders
                ++numFilesFound;
                // Process only the files of interest
                if (inFile.getName().contains(METADATA)) {
                    copyFile(inFile, new File(destinationDir.getAbsolutePath()
                            + Common.PATH_SEP + inFile.getName()));
                } else {
                    if (inFile.getName().contains(ZIPTIF)
                            || inFile.getName().contains(TIF)) {
                        if ((inFile.getName().contains(BWB)
                                && chkBoxBWB.isSelected())
                                || (inFile.getName().contains(B08)
                                && chkBoxB08.isSelected())
                                || (inFile.getName().contains(B10)
                                && chkBoxB10.isSelected())
                                || (inFile.getName().contains(B12)
                                && chkBoxB12.isSelected())) {
                            ++numTIFsFound;
                            File outFile = new File(destinationDir
                                    + Common.PATH_SEP + inFile.getName());
                            // The file is corrected here
                            fixThePix(inFile, outFile);
                        }
                    }
                    progThread
                            = new ThreadProgress(numTIFsFound / progBarMax);
                    progThread.run();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1l, 0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(FixBsPixController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }
            }
        } 
        progThread
                = new ThreadProgress(1.0);
        progThread.run();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1l, 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FixBsPixController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        btnProcess.setText("Process Images");

        if (numTIFsFound == 0) {
            updateLog("No image files found! Wrong folder?", WARNING);
            updateLog("Might want to delete " + destinationDir, INFO);
        } else {
            updateLog("Files processed " + numFilesFound
                    + "  TIFFs found: " + numTIFsFound, INFO);
            long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
            updateLog("Elapsed time: " + elapsedTime / 1_000_000 + " ms.", INFO);
            updateLog(" That's "
                    + ((double) elapsedTime / (double) numFilesFound) / 1_000_000
                    + " ms per file.", INFO);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `pf.run()` calls the thread's `run()` method on the current thread. You presumably want to start a new thread, i.e. use `pf.start()`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I've got the progress bar to work using pf.start() and a bit of help from Google.  I get a runtime error when attempting to change its color, though.

Answer (score 0):

I followed up on the comment by James_D and wrote a runnable thread to manipulate the ProgressBar's progress.

```
/** ThreadProgress updates the progress-bar in real time if
  * started with '.start()'
  */
class ThreadProgress implements Runnable {

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    ThreadProgress(double progress, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progress = progress;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}
```

I also put the working into its own runnable thread and started it
in the 'handleBtnProcessImagesClick' method.

```
@FXML
private void handleBtnProcessImagesClick(ActionEvent event) {
    Thread qif = new Thread(new QueueImageFiles());
    qif.start();
}
```

Then, in the qif (worker) thread I updated the ProgressBar when needed.

```
// first invocation
Thread progThread = new Thread(new ThreadProgress(0.0, progressBar));
progThread.start();
```

This works and I'm satisfied but what I cannot do is change the color of the progress bar.